# ConTeXt: Removing whitespace between letter sections in register table

Tags: context

I am trying to format a register table such that there are no "indicators" for each letter section and no whitespace between letter sections.

Here is my MWE:

```
\defineregister [cases]
\setupregister  [cases] [
    indicator=no,
    n=1,
    ]

\starttext

\placecases

\page[yes]

\cases{This}This is a \cases{rest}rest.

\page[yes]

\cases{This}This is a \cases{test}test.

\stoptext
```

This produces a table of cases with whitespace between letter sections:

[image: table of cases]

Is there a way to eliminate the whitespace between the line for "rest" and the line for "This"?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

ConTeXt puts the content of the `before` key at the start of a new register section even when you disable the `indicator`. The default value for the `before` key is `\blank` which results in an empty line, to remove set the key to a `empty` argument.

```
\setupregister
  [cases]
  [n=1,
   before=,
   indicator=no]
```